# How to turn off Android MediaPlayer complaints about null listeners

Tags: java, android, media-player

In my android application I use a MediaPlayer to play a sound. However, the MediaPlayer expects a bunch of different listeners to be registered: `onPreparedListener`, `onCompletionListener`, `onSeekCompleteListener`, etc. Without them, the MediaPlayer spouts out error messages to logcat:

`12-10 19:28:03.605: E/MediaPlayer(1820): mOnCompletionListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE message.`

My application does not need to do anything on these events, and so has no real need for the listeners. What's the standard way to deal with this? Should I register blank listeners? Should I not register any listeners? If so how do I turn off the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what API level you are using but these error messages don't appear to be in the Android source code for API 14+. The error messages were likely present in previous versions of Android's MediaPlayer class. If you have the latest SDK installed and the source code downloaded the class is located at: /sdk/sources/android-/android/media/MediaPlayer.java. Notice that the "TAG" variable is defined as:

```
private final static String TAG = "MediaPlayer";
```

And the OnCompletionCallback is set using:

```
public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener listener)
{
    mOnCompletionListener = listener;
}
```

This reaffirms my suspicion that you might be using an older SDK. Regardless, it would appear the easy fix would be to just add the listeners with empty callback methods. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I am running the code on my phone which is running android 4.0.4. I think that's api level 15? In my android manifest I have set targetted api level to be 15 and minimum to be 8.

Comment: I simply use this code to play a sound:
*Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
r.play();*
so I cannot add listeners to either of those objects, and I still get the irritating null ref messages...